# If I intend to use Eclipse should I install JRE 7 instead of JDK 7?

Tags: java

If I intend to use Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1 should I install JRE 7 instead of JDK 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the answer.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_do_I_get_and_install_Eclipse?)   In other words, if you will develop in Java get the JDK regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse brings its own compiler, and does not need to use the compiler in the JDK.

If you have ant projects, then ant requires a JDK for the javac task.